# "Connection failed" error when trying to telnet into SQL Server

Tags: networking, sql-server, telnet

I have an SQL Server running on a computer, and I'm trying to access it from another computer in the same local network (potentially VPN, since it's located in a datacenter). The point is that I can't even telnet to the port in which SQL Server is listening. And yes, SQL Server is working, since I can telnet to it from my workstation. I think it's something in the host, since there's no hop between the two computers, but I don't know how to troubleshoot this.
Basically I get a connection failed, when I try to telnet. What can cause such problem, since apparently there's no firewall and the server is accepting connections from other computers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to telnet to the correct port? Please post the command you're using...

Comment: telnet <ip_address> <port>
It replies me with the correct ip and port that I've tried to telnet

Comment: Have you tried running the telnet test from the server itself or from one of the other "known good" clients?

Comment: From the server itself, from my workstation and from another server in another datacenter. All fine.

Comment: If you don't know whether or not a firewall is active, and you don't know if it's across a VPN or not, I suspect that (1) you're not authorised to be doing this, (2) you're not an admin, and (3) your motives may not be honourable.

Comment: @mh - you are making a few assumptions then jumping to conclusions.  Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the computer you are using are not permitted to telnet the SQL server according to the access rule.
Can you check the privilege?

Answer (score 0):

A local area network may be split into subnets and/or VLANs divided by routers and even firewalls.

If the workstation that can telnet to the SQL server is in the same subnet/VLAN as the SQL server, and the one that doesn't work is in a different network location, then it is possible that it is a routing device that is preventing your traffic.

The SQL server may also be preventing access based on network properties of the device trying to access it.  There should be someone you can ask, but if *you* are the system administrator and don't know what is going on, you should be able to make some educated guesses after looking at the network settings (IP address, subnet, gateway) of the machines involved.